# How to ajaxify a PHP function that does SQL in the backend?

Tags: php, sql, ajax, function

I have broken down my problem to provide a concise example with no overhead.
Yet enough to give you an idea.

I have a simple index.php

```
<?php
    include 'myClass.php';
?>

<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <div> <?php myClass->printTable(); ?> </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The function returns an entire table filled with data that is being prepared in the backend.

```
<?php

function printTable()
{        
    // printing static table header
    echo '    <table class="table" style="zoom: 0.75;">
                <thead class="thead-dark">
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="col">Date</th>           // current date
                        <th scope="col">Order Number</th>   // an int
                        <th scope="col">Current Value</th>  // an int
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
        ';

    $result = mysqli_query($this->link, "SELECT * FROM `someData`");
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
    {   
        $orderNumber = $row['orderNumber'];
        $currentValue = $row['currentValue'];
        $date = $this->getDate($orderNumber);   // member function that returns a timestamp from the database

        //printing actual table
        echo '      <tr>
                        <td>'. $date .'</td>
                        <td>'. $orderNumber .'</td>
                        <td>'. $currentValue .'</td>
                    </tr>
            ';
    }

echo '       </tbody>
        </table>
    ';      
}

?>
```

The data I'm querying from my database is constantly changing. I want a "live" view on the frontend. I know this is done by using Ajax. But I don't understand how to do it. I looked up different resources, although none of them were actually specific enough in this approach.

Comment: It might help to try one of the ideas you found; then let us know what you tried and where specifically you got stuck.

Answer (score 0):

On a high level: You need a PHP file ("endpoint", e.g. 'localhost/data.php') returning only the HTML code from `printTable`. You then use JavaScript (e.g. jQuery - `$.ajax`, you can lookup how it works in detail) to fetch the contents of this page each *n* seconds and insert into your page.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for broad or unspecific way to get some data from the backend and display it within a div on my page.

The solution was to create a separate PHP (fetch.php) file that echoes only the data I need to display within my div

from my page which contains my div I'd do the following:

```
<div id="result"></div>

<script>

function load_data()
{
    $.ajax({
        url:"fetch.php",
        method:"POST",
        success:function(data)
        {
            $('#result').html(data);
        }
    });
}

load_data()

</script>
```

Inside fetch.php I can do whatever I want, including querying my database and store the values in a variable which will be echoed at the end. This response (echo) from fetch.php will then be displayed inside my div.
Similarly, I could also specify a .txt inside the ajax function (url:"sometext.txt")
The contents of the .txt could also be displayed inside my div this way. My lack of understanding of how this works made it really difficult to understand.

Additionally, I have added a function to refresh the contents (or response) every second.
If I would echo time() from fetch.php it would automatically increment without page reload inside my div

```
setInterval(function(){
    load_data()
}, 1000);
```